# Integer, float and boolean attributes inside quotes in MongoDB with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB in my Laravel project and I have a problem: I'm noticing that the fields `age`, `weight`, `height`, and `concluded` are enclosed in quotes making them look like strings:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64b41ba740f8fc543547b2d3"
  },
  "name": "Michael",
  "age": "20",
  "height": "1.89",
  "weight": "78.79",
  "begin": "2023-07-16",
  "finish": "2023-07-28",
  "concluded": "true",
  "updated_at": {
    "$date": "2023-07-16T16:33:22.423Z"
  },
  "created_at": {
    "$date": "2023-07-16T16:32:39.375Z"
  }
}
```

I expected:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64b41ba740f8fc543547b2d3"
  },
  "name": "Michael",
  "age": 20,
  "height": 1.89,
  "weight": 78.79,
  "begin": "2023-07-16",
  "finish": "2023-07-28",
  "concluded": true,
  "updated_at": {
    "$date": "2023-07-16T16:33:22.423Z"
  },
  "created_at": {
    "$date": "2023-07-16T16:32:39.375Z"
  }
}
```

##### `2023_07_08_114314_create_persons_table.php`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('persons', function (Blueprint $collection) {
        $collection->string('name');
        $collection->integer('age');
        $collection->double('height');
        $collection->double('weight');
        $collection->date('begin');
        $collection->date('finish');
        $collection->boolean('concluded')->default(false);
        $collection->timestamps();
        $collection->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

##### `PersonModel.php`

```php
class PersonModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    protected $collection = 'persons';

    protected $primary_key = '_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'age',
        'height',
        'weight',
        'begin',
        'finish',
        'concluded',
    ];
}
```

##### `PersonController.php`

```
public function store(PersonRequest $request)
{
    PersonModel::create(array_map('trim', $request->validated()));

    Log::channel('daily')->info("$request->name was added in system.");

    return redirect('/')->with('success_store', "$request->name was added in system.");
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use casts https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: @Maksim i tried make from this way, but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will cause you any issues but if you REALLY want to store integers then simply use php type declaration:

```
SomeModel::create([
    'age' => (int)$request->age ....
]);
```

This should do the magic, but yeah I'd leave it as it is since I am kinda 99% sure it wont cause any issues :D

Comment: @DevoloperBebop no probs :)